# 3 in 1 is a Trinity. What is 2 in 1, 4 in 1, 5 in 1, N in 1?

Tags: single-word-requests, religion, count

## Background

The use of the word "[Trinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinity)" occurs frequently in Catholicism when referring to God's nature, 3 persons in 1 God.  What words would describe a being that is 2 persons, 4 persons, 5 persons, etc.?

Comment: I don't like closing questions with a closed question, however well-answered it may be. +1 for a good question

Comment: In addition to the answers in the other question (*duality*, etc.), the words *composite* or *multitude* (or even [*legion*](https://biblehub.com/mark/5-9.htm), for a Biblical reference) could be used when there are more than just a few.

Comment: Not just Catholicism; all mainstream Christian denominations hold to the doctrine of the Trinity.